# Disassembling an executable that is packaged with vercel's pkg

Tags: ghidra, hex, byte-code, vm

I'm trying to reverse engineer a file that is packaged with [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg). I extracted the bytecodes from the application using [pkg-unpacker](https://github.com/LockBlock-dev/pkg-unpacker). From my understanding, application has raw js code in binary itself and that code decompress bytecode and execute it. I wrote a python script to modify that function. So, I have 2 questions

1. How do I disassemble the bytecode? I tried to use ghidra plugin but no luck for me.
2. I said, I made a Python script to modify loader JS code. I changed that code to load bytecode from directory, not from binary and it works flawlessly. But if i change a one char from string with a hex editor (Lenght of the file isn't changed). Following function returns null. How do I patch this file?

```
require("vm").Script(...).runInCurrentContext
```

Thanks for reading.